# Connecting different implementations with StructureMap

Tags: c#, generics, interface, repository, structuremap

I have a pretty straightforward generic repository:

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity, TNotFound>
    where TEntity : EntityObject
    where TNotFound : TEntity, new()
{
    IList<TEntity> GetAll();
    TEntity With(int id);
    TEntity Persist(TEntity itemToPersist);
    void Delete(TEntity itemToDelete);
}
```

I want to define a contract for a repository for the type `Term` without any special behaviour. So it looks like this:

```
public class TermNotFound : Term
{ public TermNotFound() : base(String.Empty, String.Empty) { } }


public interface ITermRepository : IRepository<Term, TermNotFound> { }
```

Now for testing, I want to create an in-memory implementation of the generic repo, so I have this (not finished for brevity):

```
public class InMemoryRepository<TEntity, TNotFound> : IRepository<TEntity, TNotFound>
    where TEntity : EntityObject
    where TNotFound : TEntity, new()
{
    private IList<TEntity> _repo = new List<TEntity>();


    public IList<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return this._repo;
    }

    public TEntity With(int id)
    {
        return this._repo.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Id == id) ?? new TNotFound();
    }

    public TEntity Persist(TEntity itemToPersist)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Delete(TEntity itemToDelete)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

It's not hard to see how I want it to work. For my tests, I want the generic `InMemoryRepository` implementation to be injected to create my `ITermRepository`.

Well, I can't get StructureMap to do it. I have tried using `WithDefaultConventions` and `ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IRepository<,>))` in the scanner without success. What can I try next?

Comment: Been a couple of years since I've last used SM so not going to post an answer, but would GetNamedInstance meet your requirement? I also believe that you can locally override the configured resolution for an interface - can't remember where that is in the api though.

Comment: Hi David. Thanks for the reply. I don't think `GetNamedInstance` will help me - I'm not naming instances in the container at this stage. I think you do that when you have many of the same instance for different uses. I only want one instance of `ITermRepository` for now, it's just creating it which is getting me stuck. I think the other option you are referring to is `IRegistrationConvention` but I'm seeing if I can avoid that first.

Comment: I was thinking you have one testing implementation (using the in memory repo) and one production implementation, is this not the case? I usually never use my ioc container for my tests, preferring to wire test fixtures by hand, but if you do use the container there I'd say you could use named instances for the test side of things.

Comment: I see what your saying, but I still don't think thats going to get me what I need. It's not about having different instances for different uses (testing, prod, etc). SM simply can't create the `ITermRepository` based on the config I have supplied. I need someone to show me how to get the right config so that SM knows how to build the `ITermRepository`. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `InMemoryRepository` doesn't implement `ITermRepository` interface. That's why you can't connect them.

The best thing you could do with what you have is injecting `InMemoryRepository<Term, TermNotFound>` for `IRepository<Term, TermNotFound>`.

If you really need to inject `ITermRepository`, then you'll need to have another repository class inheriting from `InMemoryRepository` and implementing `ITermRepository`:

```
public class InMemoryTermRepository 
    : InMemoryRepository<Term, TermNotFound>, ITermRepository
{
}
```

Now you can connect `ITermRepository` to `InMemoryTermRepository` using:

```
.For<ITermRepository>().Use<InMemoryTermRepository>()
```

If you have many interfaces like `ITermRepository`, you could create a StructureMap convention, to connect `I...Repository` to `InMemory...Repository`. The default convention is to connect `IClass` to `Class`.

Comment: Thanks for this. Some time yesterday I was looking at the interfaces and came to the same realisation as your opening statement. I guess my mind followed a path that c# could not. Thanks for clearing me up.

Comment: Not a problem. Happy to help.